# Spring Boot Camel without web shutting down immedialy

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a spring boot application with apache camel without web, that polls files from a directory and uploads files to an FTP.

Spring Boot version: 2.7.3
Apache Camel version: 3.18.1

The application is deployed in kubernetes as CronJob.

The maven pom contains the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-file-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have developed a route builder:

```
@Component
public class FtpFileUploaderRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private static final String ROUTE_ID = "ftp-file-uploader";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       
        from("file://data?&initialDelay=100&epeatCount=1")
                .toD("sftp://ftp:21?username=username&password=password");
                

    }
}
```

The main of the spring boot application is the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application .class);
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(app.run(args)));
    }

}
```

The application starts but immediatly stops.
I have set to true the following configuration: `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true`, but nothing changed.

this the log:

```
2022-09-01 14:25:05.731  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=f413b668-a57f-38f1-9e52-ff851ced3917
2022-09-01 14:25:09.379  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.18.1 (camel-1) is starting
2022-09-01 14:25:09.403  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] c.s.b.CamelSpringBootApplicationListener : Starting CamelMainRunController to ensure the main thread keeps running
2022-09-01 14:25:09.403  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [inRunController] org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport        : Apache Camel (Main) 3.18.1 is starting
2022-09-01 14:25:09.425  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup (started:1)
2022-09-01 14:25:09.425  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started ftp-file-uploader (file://target/testfiledir)
2022-09-01 14:25:09.425  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.18.1 (camel-1) started in 401ms (build:129ms init:227ms start:45ms)
2022-09-01 14:25:09.432  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] c.c.g.o.f.ServiceApplication     : Started ServiceApplication in 6.649 seconds (JVM running for 9.108)
2022-09-01 14:25:09.439  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.18.1 (camel-1) is shutting down (timeout:45s)
2022-09-01 14:25:09.452  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes stopped (stopped:1)
2022-09-01 14:25:09.452  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Stopped ftp-file-uploader (file://target/testfiledir)
2022-09-01 14:25:09.456  INFO [ftp-uploader-service,,] 41548 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.18.1 (camel-1) shutdown in 17ms (uptime:0s)
```

Comment: And why shouldn't it stop? It transfered the file, and is done... You also expliclty call `System.exit` which will kill the process.

Comment: Actually it transfer nothing. I enabled camel tracing and it doesn't transfer any file

Comment: Well you are calling `System.exit` but there is nothing to keep it alive as well. It won't wait nor poll the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/3.18.x/index.html#_making_sure_camel_context_is_running_in_standalone_spring_boot)

MAKING SURE CAMEL CONTEXT IS RUNNING IN STANDALONE SPRING BOOT

To ensure the Spring Boot application keeps running until being stopped or the JVM terminated, typically only need when running Spring Boot standalone, i.e. not with spring-boot-starter-web when the web container keeps the JVM running, set the `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` property in your configuration. For example in application.properties.

```
# to keep the JVM running
camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true
```